# Best Browser to keep a Kiosk open for weeks at a time

Tags: browser, surface-pro

I currently have a Surface Pro 7 that runs on kiosk mode for weeks at a time while staying open using Chromium Edge. The webpage starts to slow down the longer that it is open and the fix is to restart the Browser or in some cases, restart the Surface Pro. Has anyone had a similar problem that they found a solution for.

The possible solutions we are looking at is a new browser, changes to the webpage code, a new device, a new operating system (we are considering running the Surface Pros on Ubuntu, currently on Windows), or a possible browser refresh every day. Let me know if any more clarification is needed.

Comment: Is this for a specific website?  There are lightweight browsers that don't have every stinkin' feature in the world.  If you need to handle any possible web site, then my solution has usually been to force a reboot every couple of days.

Comment: It is for a single webpage that the company uses for looking up store items. We may look into a lighterweight, limited browser